# EDIT: Model for TableView with dynamic column number

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx

I am revising my question based on the comments. I have a JavaFX TableView for which the number of checkbox columns is only known at runtime. So, to create the columns, I do:

```
    TableColumn attributeColumn = new TableColumn("Attribut");
    attributeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AttributeRow, String>("name"));        
    attributeTable.getColumns().add(attributeColumn);

    for (String group : companyGroups)
    {
        TableColumn< AttributeRow, Boolean > groupColumn = new TableColumn<>( group );
        groupColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(groupColumn)); 
        groupColumn.setCellValueFactory( f -> f.getValue().activeProperty());
        groupColumn.setEditable(true);
        attributeTable.getColumns().add(groupColumn);
    }
```

The question is, how would a table model look like for this TableView? If there were a fixed number of checkbox columns, say 2 columns, my model looks like this:

```
public class AttributeRow {

private SimpleStringProperty name;
private SimpleBooleanProperty active = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);    

public AttributeRow(String name, Boolean active) {
    this.name= new SimpleStringProperty(name);         
}

public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
    if (name == null) {
        name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
    }
    return name;
}

public String getAttributeName() {
    return name.get();
}

public void setAttributeName(String fName) {
    name.set(fName);
}

public final SimpleBooleanProperty activeProperty() {
    return this.active;
}
public final boolean isActive() {
    return this.activeProperty().get();
}
public final void setActive(final boolean active) {
    this.activeProperty().set(active);
}
}
```

This model works if I have one string column and one checkbox column. But what do I do, if I have muliple checkbox columns for which the number is only known at runtime?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?  Why not change the appropriate property in the model displayed by the table?

Comment: Because I have a TableView with dynamic number of checkbox columns, that is, the number of columns can only be determined at runtime. So I cannot use a model because I don't know at designtime how many properties I really need.

Comment: How is the data represented then? Even if it's in arrays or lists that would still be possible.  `TableView` employs virtualization of cells, so changing the controls (UI) may not reliably change all data objects.

Comment: @user41854 "The number of columns can only be determined at runtime". You are only trying to set the checkboxes' selected state at runtime. So in your code, determine the number of columns and update the properties.

Comment: I have revised my question based on the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Your revised code doesn't make sense. For one thing, there is no `cellValueFactory` on the columns you create in the loop. For another, the types do not match: the table column for `attributeName` appears to have type `PrivacySetting` (so it is assuming every row in the table is an item of type `PrivacySetting`) whereas the other columns have row type `AttributeRow`; you can't have two different types here. **Where are the actual data that are being represented in the checkboxes stored?**

Comment: @James_D: Revised again and fixed the issues.

Comment: The new revised code doesn't even compile, and still doesn't make sense (all the boolean columns are referring to the same value...???). I'm not going to comment further unless there is something here that makes sense to me.

Comment: @James_D: Code should compile now. And I think your last comment is exactly my question. I don't know at designtime how many columns I have. So how can I design the model?

Comment: Why not just put a `List<Boolean>` or `List<BooleanProperty>` in your model class? (Or perhaps `<Map<String, BooleanProperty>>` since the number of booleans seems to be determined by a collection of `String`s...).

Comment: OK, sounds interesting. How would the setCellValueFactory on the checkbox column look like if I used a List<BooleanProperty>?

Comment: Why don't you post a new question which is actually asking what you need, as this seems to be the issue. Explain exactly how the data are structured and what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't really described the structure of the data, but it looks like there is some kind of collection of `String`s (`companyGroups`) and each row is the table is represented by a `String` (`name`) and one boolean for each element of `companyGroups`. So one way to do this would just be to define a `Map<String, BooleanProperty>` in the model class `AttributeRow`, where the key in the map is intended to be an element of `companyGroups`:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class AttributeRow {

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private final Map<String, BooleanProperty> activeByGroup = new HashMap<>();

    public AttributeRow(List<String> companyGroups) {
        for (String group : companyGroups) {
            activeByGroup.put(group, new SimpleBooleanProperty()) ;
        }
    }

    public final BooleanProperty activeProperty(String group) {
        // might need to deal with the case where
        // there is no entry in the map for group
        // (else calls to isActive(...) and setActive(...) with 
        // a non-existent group will give a null pointer exception):

        return activeByGroup.get(group) ;
    }

    public final boolean isActive(String group) {
        return activeProperty(group).get();
    }

    public final void setActive(String group, boolean active) {
        activeProperty(group).set(active);
    }

    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }


    public final String getName() {
        return this.nameProperty().get();
    }


    public final void setName(final String name) {
        this.nameProperty().set(name);
    }



}
```

There is nothing special about the cell value factory for the columns - it still just has to map each row to the appropriate observable property for the column:

```
for (String group : groups) {
    TableColumn<AttributeRow, Boolean> groupColumn = new TableColumn<>(group);
    groupColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(groupColumn));
    groupColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().activeProperty(group));
    attributeTable.getColumns().add(groupColumn);
}
```

and of course to update values you just update the model:

```
Button selectAll = new Button("Select all");
selectAll.setOnAction(e -> {
    for (AttributeRow row : attributeTable.getItems()) {
        for (String group : groups) {
            row.setActive(group, true);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a SSCCE:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithMappedBooleans extends Application {

    private static final List<String> groups = Arrays.asList("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableView<AttributeRow> attributeTable = new TableView<>();
        attributeTable.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<AttributeRow, String> attributeColumn = new TableColumn<>("Attribute");
        attributeColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());

        attributeTable.getColumns().add(attributeColumn);

        for (String group : groups) {
            TableColumn<AttributeRow, Boolean> groupColumn = new TableColumn<>(group);
            groupColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(groupColumn));
            groupColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().activeProperty(group));
            attributeTable.getColumns().add(groupColumn);
        }

        // generate data:
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 10; i++) {
            AttributeRow row = new AttributeRow(groups);
            row.setName("Attribute "+i);
            attributeTable.getItems().add(row);
        }

        // button to select everything:

        Button selectAll = new Button("Select all");
        selectAll.setOnAction(e -> {
            for (AttributeRow row : attributeTable.getItems()) {
                for (String group : groups) {
                    row.setActive(group, true);
                }
            }
        });

        // for debugging, to check data are updated from check boxes:
        Button dumpDataButton = new Button("Dump data");
        dumpDataButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            for (AttributeRow row : attributeTable.getItems()) {
                String groupList = groups.stream()
                        .filter(group -> row.isActive(group))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
                System.out.println(row.getName() + " : " + groupList);
            }
            System.out.println();
        });

        HBox buttons = new HBox(5, selectAll, dumpDataButton);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        buttons.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(attributeTable, null, null, buttons, null);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks James_D. I am impressed. It works. Please apologize my poor initial question. Thanks for helping me anyway. :-)